# Ошибка cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. В jq я не силен, скажу сразу :)

Имеется Jq код который получает данные как я понимаю с блока:

`var nextD = $('.check-item[data-id="' + currentID + '"]').next().data().id;`

Имеется этот же блок:

`<div data-id="'.$list[3].'" class="check-item">'.$Name1.' - '.$Name2.'</div>`

Если оставить так, все работает, данные получаются, но если я хочу перед блоком добавить еще один блок:

`<div clas="ddd">'.$j.'</div>
 <div data-id="'.$list[3].'" class="check-item">'.$Name1.' - '.$Name2.'</div>`

То получаю ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` которая ссылается на кусок кода который я привел в начале. Почему так происходит?

Comment: убери вызов `next`. _Имеется Jq код который получает данные как я понимаю с блока_ - получает данные из элемента _после_ выбранного

Comment: @Grundy я бы с удовольствием убрал, но у меня генерируется 20 однотипных элементов в которых меняется лишь `data-id` и мне нужно по очереди получать их значения

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему у тебя генерируется много однотипных элементов

```
<div data-id="'.$list[3].'" class="check-item">'.$Name1.' - '.$Name2.'</div>
```

а
  метод `next()` берет следующий за выбранным селектором  `$('.check-item[data-id="' + currentID + '"]')` элемент далее по DOMу. И как раз таки тот что ты добавил между элементами `.check-item` не имеет data-id собственно поэтому и undefined. Если ты добавишь этому элементу data-id то ошибки не возникнет. Если data-id тебе ставить не нужно для этого элемента, то укажи в next() какой именно элемент тебе нужен:

`$('.check-item[data-id=' + currentID + ']').nextAll("div[data-id].check-item:first").attr('data-id');`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentID = 4;
  var nextD = $('.check-item[data-id=' + currentID + ']').nextAll("div[data-id].check-item:first").attr('data-id');
  alert(nextD);
})
```

```css
.check-item {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div data-id="1" class="check-item">some name</div>
<div data-id="4" class="check-item">some name</div>
<div class="check-item">o</div>
<div data-id="ds">some without class</div>
<div data-id="8" class="check-item">some name</div>
<div data-id="2" class="check-item">some name</div>
<div data-id="5" class="check-item">some name</div>
<div data-id="9" class="check-item">some name</div>
```

Comment: Вы правы, ошибка больше не появляется, но Jq начал брать непонятно откуда значения data-id. Далеко не те, которые указаны в `.check-item`

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант оказался рабочим. Можно на последок задать один вопрос. А если я захочу `<div data-id="2" class="check-item">some name</div>` заключить в `<ol>`. Что бы получилось `<ol><div data-id="2" class="check-item">some name</div></ol>`, как быть в таком случае? тогда ваш код перестает работать)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentID = 4;
  var nextD = $('.check-item[data-id=' + currentID + ']').nextAll("div[data-id].check-item:first").attr('data-id');
  alert(nextD);
})
```

```css
.check-item {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div data-id="1" class="check-item">some name</div>
<div data-id="4" class="check-item">some name</div>
<div class="check-item">o</div>
<div data-id="ds">some without class</div>
<div data-id="8" class="check-item">some name</div>
<div data-id="2" class="check-item">some name</div>
<div data-id="5" class="check-item">some name</div>
<div data-id="9" class="check-item">some name</div>
```